# Pattern module conjugation: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, python-2.7, design-patterns, tuples

I am trying to write an extended conjugation function using pattern package. For example, when trying to use the following tuple for the conjugation of the verb allege:

```
 tuple = ('allege', 3, 'future', 'plural', 'subjunctive', 'progressive', False)
```

I get the `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'.`

When I print tuple items, they get printed out nicely, even the integer item of the tuple, however when I try to use them in the conjugate functions, as follows:

```
 conjugate(tuple[0], tuple[1], tuple[2], tuple[3], tuple[4], tuple[5], tuple[6])
```

I get the `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'` error and cannot use it in the `conjugate()` function.

Can somebody help me out with this issue.

Comment: Can you post the `conjugate` function?

Answer (score 0):

One of your variables inside the `conjugate` function is of `int` type.

Example

```
i = 1
i.lower()
```

Most likely it's `tuple[1]`, that's giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I completely forgot to post my function. I resolved the issue in the meanwhile and here is the solution in case somebody would use it in the future.

This is a function that generates list of tuples with parameters needed for verb conjugation:

```
def tuple_generate(list):
    """function generates list of all possible tuples for a list of verbs,  
    consisting of arguments needed for verb conjugation using
    pattern.en conjugate function"""
    value = 0
    L = []
    import pattern
    from pattern.en import conjugate
    tense = ['present', 'past', 'future']
    person = [1, 2, 3]
    number = ["singular", "plural"]
    mood = ["indicative", "imperative", "conditional", "subjunctive"]
    aspect = ["imperfective", "perfective", "progressive"]
    negated = [False, True]
    for i, a, b, c, d, e, f in [(i, a, b, c, d, e, f) for i in list for a in tense for b in person for c in number for d in mood for e in aspect for f in negated]:
        x = i, a, b, c, d, e, f
        #print x
        value += 1
        L.append(x)
    return L
```

And the conjugate function itself:

```
def verb_conjugate(list):
    """function conjugates tuples of verbs and associated arguments
    needed in the pattern.en conjugate function"""
    import pattern
    from pattern.en import conjugate
    V = []
    value  = 0
    for tuple in list:
        x = conjugate(tuple[0], tuple[1], tuple[2], tuple[3], tuple[4], tuple[5], tuple[6])
        value += 1
        V.append(x)
        V = sorted(set(V))
        for i in V:
            if i == None:
                V.remove(i)
    return V
```

There is probably a more elegant solution for what I did but this is from the land of Python grasshoppers. :)

bets,

G